# Stopping coroutine from other script not a calling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I need to stop a coroutine running in another script when the player hits a trigger. The trigger works, however the coroutine doesn't stop.

Here is the script that runs the coroutine:

```
 public AudioSource direction;

public IEnumerator audioPlayCoroutine;

public bool running = false;

IEnumerator AudioPlay()
{
    while (true)
    {
        direction.Play();

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    }

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {

        if (running == false)
        {
            audioPlayCoroutine = AudioPlay();

            StartCoroutine(audioPlayCoroutine);

            Debug.Log("Started");

            running = true;
        }

        else if (running == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Void");
        }

    }           

}
```

This is the script to stop the coroutine running.

```
public GameObject lastTrigger;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {

        Debug.Log("Triggered");

        if (lastTrigger.GetComponent<MazeAudioLoop>().running == true)
        {

            lastTrigger.GetComponent<MazeAudioLoop>().running = false;

            Debug.Log("Running: false");

            StopCoroutine(lastTrigger.GetComponent<MazeAudioLoop>().audioPlayCoroutine);

        }
    }
}
```

The triggered debug shows, however the coroutine does not stop.

Comment: did you try rather using `audioPlayCoroutine = StartCoroutine(AudioPlay());` ? Are the conditions `true` and the line of `StopCoroutine` actually reached? And you should store the result of `GetComponent` and not call it multiple times. E.g. by making `public MazeAudioLoop lastTrigger;` and only use `GetComponent` once when setting that field

Comment: @derHugo that's more of an answer than a comment.

Comment: @trollingchar it is a question ;) so rather a comment. `IEnumerator xy = AudioPlay(); StarCoroutine(xy);` should basically work the same way as `Coroutine xy = StartCoroutine(AudioPlay());`

Comment: You stated `Triggered` is printed to the console ... but do you get the `Running: false` log? If not it simply means that `lastTrigger.GetComponent<MazeAudioLoop>().running` is `false` ...

Comment: I would have had under your first class, a "stopaudio" method,to try keep it in one place, or even change the audio to be triggered and stopped by the value of "running" even simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call StopCoroutine on the component running the coroutine.

```
  StopCoroutine(lastTrigger.GetComponent<MazeAudioLoop>().audioPlayCoroutine);
```

this means the current component is about to stop a coroutine it does not hold.

Instead, you could create a simple method to stop the coroutine:

```
MazeAudioLoop mal = lastTrigger.GetComponent<MazeAudioLoop>();
if (mal.running == true)
{
     mal.running = false
     mal.StopAudio();
      // or this => mal.StopCoroutine(mal.audioPlayCoroutine);
}
```

and the MazeAudioLoop.cs has:

```
public void StopAudio()
{
     if(audioPlayCoroutine == null) { return; }
     StopCoroutine(audioPlayCoroutine);
     audioPlayCoroutine = null;
}
```